# Qt5 Android deployment issue

Tags: java, android, qt

Two years ago I developed a Qt4 Android app using Ministro and it worked perfectly in that time. Right now I am porting the same code into Qt5. After updating several files I could compile and create the APK file in a pretty clean way.
Nevertheless, when I try to deploy the app into my tablet, it crashes showing these two error messages:

```
No implementation found for int[] org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.extractNativeChunkInfo()
```

And:

```
E/libEGL  (11187): cache file failed CRC check
```

These are my settings:

- QtCreator with Qt 5.5.1
- Android Studio (Android 5.0.1 - API Level 21)
- Android NDK (r10e)
- Ant (1.9.6)
- JDK (1.8.0_73)

Note: I tried to deploy my app from a virtual android device (using API 23) and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the problem in a very strange way: I removed all the Android references in my code, including the android manifest.
In other words, I transformed my app into a "desktop" solution. Then, from QtCreator I made the deployment pointing to android and everything worked in a pretty clean way. I wonder how Qt solutions have evolved as an actual resource for mobile development in just few years.